# cast of objective-c pointer type nsoutputstream* to c pointer type cfwritestreamref exception after __bridge

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

i am working on a project that t¨sends a photo with smtp . In the beginning automatic reference counting was disabled and the project was running without problems . When i enabled automatic reference counting i got many compilation errors. One of the most common was Cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSOutputStream*' to C pointer type CFWriteStreamRef (aka 'struct_CFWriteStream*' requires a bridged cast)  at the lines

```
if (CFWriteStreamWriteFully(( CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, (const uint8_t *)[ehlo  
UTF8String], [ehlo lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) < 0)
```

When i write 
    if (CFWriteStreamWriteFully((__bridge CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, (const uint8_t *)
    [ehlo UTF8String], [ehlo lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) < 0)

it compiles but i get a runtime exception when i press the send button to send an email with smtp. I was wondering if you could help me with this problem. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance, Best regards

Answer (score 0):

How can you be sure it's a wrong typeCast? 
Try to keep the ownership of [ehlo  UTF8String] as long as the stream is writing, maybe that can help

```
const UInt8 *buffer = (const UInt8 *)[ehlo UTF8String];
if (CFWriteStreamWriteFully(( CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, buffer, [ehlo lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) < 0)
```

By the way i haven't fount CFWriteStreamWriteFully() declaration anywhere. Only CFIndex

```
CFWriteStreamWrite (
   CFWriteStreamRef stream,
   const UInt8 *buffer,
   CFIndex bufferLength
);
```

Are there related?
UInt8 and uint8_t are both unsigned char.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help . However i tried that and it did not work. The code is as follows:
    if (CFWriteStreamWriteFully((CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream,                          
    const uint8_t *)[ehlo  UTF8String], [ehlo            
    lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) < 0)
    {
    error =  [outputStream streamError];
    encounteredError = YES;
    }
    else{
    [self startShortWatchdog];
    }

Comment: CFIndex    CFWriteStreamWriteFully(CFWriteStreamRef outputStream,            
    const uint8_t* 
    buffer, CFIndex length)
    {
    CFIndex bufferOffset = 0;
    CFIndex bytesWritten;
    
    while (bufferOffset < length)
    {
    if (CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(outputStream))
    {
    bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(outputStream, &       
    (buffer[bufferOffset]), - bufferOffset);
    if (bytesWritten < 0)
    {
    // Bail!
    return bytesWritten;
    }

Comment: bufferOffset += bytesWritten;
    }
    else  if (CFWriteStreamGetStatus(outputStream)
    ==kCFStreamStatusError)
    return -1;
    }
    else
    {
    // Pump the runloop
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.0, true);
    }
    }
    
    return bufferOffset;
    }
    [self startShortWatchdog];
    }

Comment: Ok, then you should show your stack error, it will be simpler. Then we could see where the error actually happen

Comment: The exception happens at line:
    if CFWriteStreamWriteFully((  CFWriteStreamRefoutputStream,   
    (const uint8_t *)[ehlo
    UTF8String], [ehlo   
    lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) < 0)
and the stack error is                                             self SKPSMTPMessage *(where SKPSMTPMessage is the current class) 0x1fdc9860
buffer const UInt8 * 0x210bfaf0
ehlo __NSCFString * 0x210bfa70
outputStream NSOutputStream * 0x00000000
NSStream NSStream 
NSObject NSObject 
isa Class

Comment: #0 0x357179a6 in CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes ()
#1 0x000581e2 in CFWriteStreamWriteFully at /Users/ediff/Desktop/xcode projects/formal backup/backup of testsendwithsmtp/23 10 17 15 backup/TestSendWithSMTP/TestSendWithSMTP/HSK_CFUtilities.m:36
#2 0x0005aac6 in -[SKPSMTPMessage parseBuffer] at /Users/ediff/Desktop/xcode projects/formal backup/backup of testsendwithsmtp/23 10 17 15 backup/TestSendWithSMTP/TestSendWithSMTP/SKPSMTPMessage.m:344

Comment: #3 0x00059fd2 in -[SKPSMTPMessage stream:handleEvent:] at /Users/ediff/Desktop/xcode projects/formal backup/backup of testsendwithsmtp/23 10 17 15 backup/TestSendWithSMTP/TestSendWithSMTP/SKPSMTPMessage.m:246
#4 0x356d87ce in _signalEventSync ()
#8 0x3542edd8 in CoreReadStreamClient::coreStreamEventsAvailable(unsigned long) ()

Comment: You should edit it into your post, that'll be more readable ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest/help . I finally found another way to solve this problem. I enabled automatic reference counting for the whole project but not for these two classes that have the bridge problems and this solved the problem. I went to build phases  and in these two classes i wrote -fno-objc-arc. Cheers!!!